# Meaning of "Out for revenge"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Claude Frollo had always stayed away from
>   women. But now he seemed to hate them—
>   especially gypsy women. He had asked the
>   bishop to forbid gypsies from dancing in the
>   square. He was outraged when the bishop
>   refused. For some reason he seemed to be **out
>   for revenge**. He began to collect information
>   about all the wizards and witches 
>   who’d been
>   burned or hanged in the past.

Dose it mean: He began to take revenge openly.

Answer (score 1):

***[Be out for something/be out to do something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-out-for-something-be-out-to-do-something)*** is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> (informal) to have a particular intention
>
> - *Andrew’s just out for a good time.
>     I was convinced he was out to cheat me.*

So,

> to be out for revange means *to have the clear intention to seek revange on something/someone.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Shoudn't it be: to be out for revange means to have clear intention to seek revange on something/someone. you wrote: .... to have **the** clear intention to ....

Answer (score 0):

"Out for revenge" means approximately "planning or taking action to seek revenge." In other words, it seems like his mission or intention is to get revenge.